# Passing a variable from Activity to Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, interface

My Activity implements an interface called MyInterface that has a method called getList. This method grabs a arrayList of objects and returns it at the end. I am trying to access the variable in another fragment and have been struggling to do so. I have looked into bundling, intents, parcelables and have been using the current interface route. How do I access the variable in my Fragment?

Below is my getList method which returns the object of arraylists called **arrayListAndroidContacts**

```
   public ArrayList<Android_Contact> getList() {
        ArrayList<Android_Contact> arrayListAndroidContacts = new ArrayList<Android_Contact>();

        //--< get all Contacts >--
        Cursor cursor_Android_Contacts = null;
        ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
        try {
            cursor_Android_Contacts = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
        } catch (
                Exception ex
                )
        {
            Log.e("Error on contact", ex.getMessage());
        }
        if (cursor_Android_Contacts.getCount() > 0)

        {
//----< has Contacts >----
//----< @Loop: all Contacts >----
            while (cursor_Android_Contacts.moveToNext()) {
//< init >
                Android_Contact android_contact = new Android_Contact();
                String contact_id = cursor_Android_Contacts.getString(cursor_Android_Contacts.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                String contact_display_name = cursor_Android_Contacts.getString(cursor_Android_Contacts.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
//</ init >

//----< set >----
                android_contact.android_contact_Name = contact_display_name;


//----< get phone number >----
                int hasPhoneNumber = Integer.parseInt(cursor_Android_Contacts.getString(cursor_Android_Contacts.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)));
                if (hasPhoneNumber > 0) {

                    Cursor phoneCursor = contentResolver.query(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI
                            , null
                            , ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?"
                            , new String[]{contact_id}
                            , null);

                    while (phoneCursor.moveToNext()) {
                        String phoneNumber = phoneCursor.getString(phoneCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
//< set >
                        android_contact.android_contact_TelefonNr = phoneNumber;
//</ set >
                    }
                    phoneCursor.close();
                }

                arrayListAndroidContacts.add(android_contact);

            }


            Collections.reverse(arrayListAndroidContacts);

            Adapter_for_Android_Contacts adapter = new Adapter_for_Android_Contacts(this, arrayListAndroidContacts);

            ListView listView_Android_Contacts = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview_Android_Contacts);

            listView_Android_Contacts.setAdapter(adapter);

        }
        return arrayListAndroidContacts;
    }
```

This is my Fragment which currently contains my instance of the interface, my adapter for the listview and the a call to the value of **arrayListAndroidContacts**

```
public class Tab1Recents extends Fragment {
    MyInterface myInterface;

    public static final String MESSAGE_KEY = "message_key";

    public void onAttach(MainActivity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            myInterface = (MyInterface) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement onViewSelected");
        }
    }




    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {


        Adapter_for_Android_Contacts adapter = new Adapter_for_Android_Contacts(this, arrayListAndroidContacts);

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1_recent, container, false);

        ListView recentContacts = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recent_Android_Contacts);

        recentContacts.setAdapter(adapter);

        return rootView;
    }

    public class Adapter_for_Android_Contacts extends BaseAdapter {

        Context mContext;
        List<MainActivity.Android_Contact> mList_Android_Contacts;

        //< constructor with ListArray >
        public Adapter_for_Android_Contacts(Context mContext, List<MainActivity.Android_Contact> mContact) {
            this.mContext = mContext;
            this.mList_Android_Contacts = mContact;
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return mList_Android_Contacts.size();
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return mList_Android_Contacts.get(position);
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view = View.inflate(mContext, R.layout.contactlist_android_items, null);
            TextView textview_contact_Name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textview_android_contact_name);
            textview_contact_Name.setText(mList_Android_Contacts.get(position).android_contact_Name);
            view.setTag(mList_Android_Contacts.get(position).android_contact_Name);
            return view;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: One way is to store the list in a SQLite database.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice in the long run I suspect this to be the best route. Any tutorials or leads on how to use that within Android/Java framework?

Comment: why don't you put the list into argument when creating the fragment? You use the list in onCreateView method, you should not call the getList() in the method because querying data should be in a worker thread.

Comment: I suggest Google.

Answer (score 0):

First, you use `ContentResolver` to query, so `getList()` should be invoked in a non-UI thread(so, the creation of adapter and update for ListView must not be in this method.

Then you can start a async thread/task/service to invoke `getList()` from activity or fragment.

Once **arrayListAndroidContacts** comes, you can use `View.post(Runnable)` to post an UI operation(create adapter and update ListView), or use `BroadcastReceiver`, or use `EventBus`. Choose one that you prefer.

Comment: I tried adding the whole getList method to my fragment however ContentResolver is unfamiliar even though I have the necessary using staements. Know why?